# Who actually holds a speed record: the driver or the vehicle?

Tags: auto-racing

It seems intuitive to me that the holder of a speed record would be the vehicle. For example, the current land speed record was set using the [ThrustSSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThrustSSC). Presumably all the driver needs to do is find a sufficiently long piece of flat land, then press the accelerator to the ground until the car ceases to accelerate.

However if this is the case, then I don't understand why there's a Guinness world record for the [fastest land speed achieved by a woman](https://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/fastest-land-speed-record-(female)/). After all, to break this record, just get any woman to drive the ThrustSSC.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about sports.